# Testing CSS color with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

This is a simple HTML/JavaScript file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<title>Javascript</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>  
.red {
    color:rgb(255,0,0); 
}
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <p class="red">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy developer.</p>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("p").each (function (index,element) {
        var color = $(element).css("color");
        alert("color=" + color); //the alert says color=rgb(255,0,0)
        if (color==rgb(255,0,0)) {
            alert("color is rgb(255,0,0)"); 
           //this alert never fires and the  code never gets here.
            $(element).css("color","#000000");
            $(element).css("background-color","#ffff00");
        } 
    });
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Why does the test `if (color==rgb(255,0,0)` fail? Isn't the color `rgb(255,0,0)`? Does seem to matter if the test says `color="red"`, either.

Comment: That code gets you back the actual value set for the 'color' css attribute for the element. So if you're setting the color via a class, you won't get the color value you're expecting

Comment: Try adding quotes: `color == "rgb(255,0,0)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `.css("color")` returns a string, so you have to compare it to a string. Also, since you are doing a string comparison, whitespace is important: `rgb(255,0,0) !== rgb(255, 0, 0)`.

This works just fine:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  $("p").each(function(index, element) {
    var color = $(element).css("color");
    alert('color=' + color);
    if (color == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
      alert("color is rgb(255,0,0)");

      $(element).css("color", "#000000");
      $(element).css("background-color", "#ffff00");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .red {
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  }
</style>

<p class="red">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy developer.</p>
```

Comment: Your solution worked. It worked even when in the definition for .red it was color:#FF0000;